# Excel logical operator `<=` does not return expected TRUE

Tags: excel-formula

I am using the logical operator `<=` in Excel to compare a manually entered number `used data` and a calculated value `total with roll-over` to produce that value `overage`. Here is a screenshot of the data (a cut-and-pastable version of these data is at the bottom):

[image]

The formula for `total with roll-over` in cell E2 is:

```
=D2+IFERROR(IF(D1-F1>0,D1-F1,0),0)
```

and this formula was copied down the `roll-over` column. The formula for `overage` in cell G2 is:

```
=IF((E2-F2)<=0,"all data used","")
```

and was copied down the `overage` column.

The unexpected behavior is in cell G11, which I would expect to return `all data used` because 8.69 - 8.69 = 0, similar to cell G13. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

**Additional data on floating point error**
Before posting my original question, I tried to check for a floating point error by increasing the number of decimal points displayed and using scientific notation (see screen shot). I didn't detect a floating point error, but `I like Excel very much`'s solution fixed the problem, so floating point error must be the underlying cause. I'll need to find a new way of checking for this type of error.

[image]

Pastable data:

```
    new data    total with roll-over    used data   overage
jan 8   8.00    3.79    
feb 8   12.21   5.38    
mar 8   10.62   5.45    
apr 8   10.55   0.07    
may 8   15.93   0.00    
jun 8   16.00   5.13    
jul 8   10.87   5.63    
aug 8   10.37   8.28    
sep 8   8.00    7.31    
oct 8   8.69    8.69
```

Comment: there is a possibilty that there are more decimal values than what is being shown.  Try: `=IF((round(E2,2)-round(F2,2))<=0,"all data used","")`  Just because it shows only two decimals does not mean that Excel is storing only two decimals.

Comment: In response to your edit:

I discovered the error by clicking "evaluate formula" and following along, but you can recreate the error in a cell by putting the references in brackets ( ).

Using your data set try this formula:

 `=(E11-F11)`.

 Excel will try to compensate when addition or subtraction causes a value at or near zero. For some reason brackets break that.

Comment: Thank you. Enclosing the formula in parentheses revealed the floating point issue. Why is Microsoft so terrible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations, you have discovered a floating point error.

Excel is evaluating `8.69 - 8.69` as `1.7763568390025E-15`. The way around it is to pick how many decimal points you care about and round to that.

In this example 10 digits should be more than enough, use this formula:

`=IF(ROUND(E11-F11,10)<=0,"all data used","")`

Which will round off anything after the 10th decimal point and avoid the error.

[Here's Microsoft's explanation of floating point errors](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/)